# Trying to add record via AJAX using asp.net core MVC; model is empty when passed via jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm certain I'm overlooking something obvious here, but here's the problem. I have an "add comment" feature I'd like to handle asynchronously that requires (for simplicity's sake) two properties: PostId and CommentText.

I have the following handler set up in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddComment(AddCommentModel acm) {

                //fun stuff goes here

                return PartialView("CommentList",scl);
}
```

And my jQuery call is like so:

$("#btnPostComment").click(
                function () {

```
                var comment = $("#userComment").val();
                var id = $("#postId").val();



                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Post/AddComment",
                    type: "post",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ acm: { Comment: comment, PostId: id } }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#partial").html(result);
                    },
                    error: function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                        alert("Failed to process promotion correctly, please try again");
                        console.log('xhRequest: ' + xhRequest + "\n");
                        console.log('ErrorText: ' + ErrorText + "\n");
                        console.log('thrownError: ' + thrownError + "\n");
                    }
                });
            }
        );
```

What obvious and embarrassing thing am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what worked for me:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddComment([FromBody]AddCommentModel acm)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please replace your code with this and see.

In controller,

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddComment(string Comment, int PostId) {

    //fun stuff goes here

    return PartialView("CommentList",scl);
}
```

On button click

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Post/AddComment",
    type: "post",
    data: { Comment: comment, PostId: id },
    success: function (result) {
        $("#partial").html(result);
        },
    error: function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
        alert("Failed to process promotion correctly, please try again");
        console.log('xhRequest: ' + xhRequest + "\n");
        console.log('ErrorText: ' + ErrorText + "\n");
        console.log('thrownError: ' + thrownError + "\n");
        }
      });
```

Comment: Thanks; I tried that before posting, with the same frustrating result.